# Using d3 how to pass multiple row data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some code that looks like this:

```
var row = 4;
var col = 4;
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
var layers = stack( d3.range(row).map(function() {
    return CmcLayer(col); 
}));

function CmcLayer(col) {
    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return a.map(function(d, i) { return {x: i, y: d}; });
}
```

Optimally I'd like to pass in data that looks like this, or similar to this:

```
var a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
         [4, 3, 2, 1],
         [1, 2, 3, 4],
         [4, 3, 2, 1]];
```

What do I have to change so it will accept multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the answer for posterity.

```
    var stack = d3.layout.stack();
    var layers = stack( CmcLayerData() );

    function CmcLayerData() {
        var data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], // bottom
                    [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    [4, 2, 3, 4]]; // top

        data = data.map(function(d) { 
            return d.map(function(i, j) { 
                return {x:j, y:i, y0:0};
            });
        });

        return data;
    }
```